# What is the equivalent of layer-list in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

What is the equivalent of layer-list in jetpack compose?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/lightGray" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/transp_01" />
</layer-list>
```

I want to get an image like the one shown to use as a background for all my screens

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw it easily in compose. With `Box` you can place any amount of images on top of each other same as layer list can do. So generally specking, you could use something like this:

```
Box {
    // replace any color item from the layer list with box with background:
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .matchParentSize()
    )
    // replace drawable item with Image:
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.my_image),
        contentDescription = "...",
    )
}
```

But in your case, it looks like you only need one image, and you can set a background color for it. Since you need to reuse it in your application, you can move it to a separate view, for example like this:

```
@Composable
fun BackgroundView(modifier: Modifier) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.transp_01),
        contentDescription = "...",
        modifier = modifier.background(Color.LightGray)
    )
}
```

Then set it as background to any screen like this:

```
@Composable
fun SomeScreen() {
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        BackgroundView(Modifier.matchParentSize())
        // screen content
    }
}
```

Comment: This is equivalent in terms of the visual result but not in the sense it bypasses the resource system.